# Defining own command

Tags: macros

I'm trying to create a command to save me some heartache when writing the rest of this document.  What I'm attempting to do is to create a command like `\double{-}`, which when used will produce:

`\llbracket - \rrbracket`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other solution is good, and is in general the way that you'd define a command. Just to add on a little bit of handy info -- The `mathtools` package provides `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, which is super useful for exactly this sort of thing. For example,

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\double{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}
```

defines a command that simply surrounds an argument in double braces like the other answer:

```
\double{n}
```

or scale itself with a size parameter like `\big`:

```
\double[\Bigg]{x}
```

or even automatically scale itself to fit whatever's inside:

```
\double*{\frac{\sum i}{\prod j}}
```

Chances are this is overkill for whatever you're doing, but it's always nice to know what's available to you, eh?

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly easy to do, simply do:

```
\newcommand{\double}[1]{\llbracket #1 \rrbracket}
```

Based on: [latex newcommand guide](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_19.html)